# Mercurial workflow with subrepositories and offline clones?

Tags: mercurial, workflow, offline, subrepos

I'm offline a lot.

So normally, I use one local clone as a "hub" for features, bugs, etc.

```
hg clone local-hub bug-123
```

Works offline.  Cool.

Can I use a similar workflow if that project contains remote subrepositories?

Because, if .hgsub says

```
sub/shared = http://server/hg/shared
```

hg clone says

```
abort: error: getaddrinfo failed
```

Note that once the clone is created (while connected), `push` and `pull` will use the path in the subrepo's `hgrc` (instead of the location in `.hgsub`).  So I can point this to a local clone and everything is cool.

But `clone` looks at `.hgsub` (as it's supposed to).  So if the "blessed" subrepo is on a server, I can't create new clones offline, even though the files I need are right there.

This is a problem, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ideally whomever set up the project uses relative URLs in their .hgsub file like this:

```
sub/shared = ../shared
```

and then, of course, actually makes shared a sibling of the main repo.  Then as long as you have cloned down the main repo and the subs (as siblings) then everything will work out.

If they've used absolute URLs in their .hgsub file you can work around it using the subpaths section in your .hgrc like this:

```
[subpaths]
http://server/hg/shared = ../shared
```

which provides a translation layer in your client.

Comment: Hey, thanks!  I've read a lot of your writing in my research on this subject... you're a great contributor here.  Both options have merits, and I will have to consider which is best for me.  Thanks again!

Comment: ok, there's one sticking point un-hassle-y'd ;-)  Is it just me or are sub-repos hard to figure out?

Comment: @qes they are admittedly hard to figure out.  Part of the trouble is that most Mercurial developers don't use them, and those that do are only working on the use cases that affect them.

Answer (score 2):

The canonical way to use subrepositories is to have `X = X` paths in the `.hgsub` file:

```
sub/shared = sub/shared
```

That way a clone will structurally look just like the original -- and so you can use the clone to make further (local!) clones.

However, this is not always possible, for example, Bitbucket wont let you create the nested repositories on their server. In that case, the `../X` style paths in the `.hgsub` file is better, and you can use the [subpaths configuration section](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#subpaths) to translate these paths into paths you can use locally.

Comment: Thanks, Martin.  Point for SO; 2 responses, both from experts on the topic.  I am definitely interested in the most "canonical" use of subrepos.  But doesn't **sub/shared = sub/shared** imply that the subrepo "lives" under the parent, and is thus not really shared?  In other words, since .hgsub is actually tracked, shouldn't the right side be the path to the "blessed" subrepo?  **../X** seems the most flexible solution.  As long as **../X** is a valid location, then clones will look just like the original.

Comment: @harpo: No, they can still be shared on the server. Please see [my other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7318280/110204) for three different ways of accomplishing this.