# Mercurial abort: error: getaddrinfo failed AFTER clone/updating

Tags: mercurial

I've looked up the general error message, but it always seems to come immediately after an attempt to clone the repository. I'm using `hg serve` if that helps shed any light on this.

C:\workspace\Project>hg clone --pull `http://host:8001` client 
requesting all changes
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
added 1556 changesets with 6734 changes to 2367 files (+1 heads)
updating to branch trunk
abort: error: getaddrinfo failed

Comment: Does the repository contain a sub repository on a different server?

Comment: if you are working with subrepositories, [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5177054/mercurial-workflow-with-subrepositories-and-offline-clones) elsewhere hereabouts might be useful too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments you've received allude to, I think the repository you're cloning contain sub-repositories.

The error message is saying that Mercurial can't find the IP address for something (i.e. a DNS lookup has failed), but you've obviously managed to connect to the server with the initial repository on it. Sub-repositories are cloned during the update process of the parent. The fact that you're getting the error just after the `updating to branch trunk` message leads to the conclusion that this is your problem.

Look at the contents of `.hgsub` in the original repository. If it has anything in it, it will have the URLs of any sub-repositories. I suspect these URLs have been written in a way that means they aren't accessible from the machine you're trying to clone to. If possible, fix these to make them general enough to work anywhere.

That error message should really say what it was looking up and why.